# How can I see close and reopen history of a question that wasn't edited?

Tags: support, faq, edits, timeline

When a question was edited, the close and reopen events appear in the edit history. But when a question wasn't edited at all there's no link to the history, so we can't see these events.

Is there an alternative way to view these events?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: [Show Timeline userscript](https://github.com/Tunaki/stackoverflow-userscripts/blob/master/showtimeline.user.js)

Comment: [Another user script that adds the timeline and history links](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/blob/master/SEModifications.user.js)

Comment: @NathanOliver: I couldn't find the source for that one :D

Comment: FAQ? This seems like an AQ, but is it really frequently asked for people besides power users of the site?

Comment: @hichris123 What's your concern actually? I don't get it?

Comment: I'm just confused why this was made into an FAQ -- usually our FAQs are much more general and are the key guidelines for users to follow.

Comment: @hichris123 I never intended this question to go to the FAQ, but it seems many of us just need to externalize their rememberings here because of beginning Alzheimer disease ;)

Comment: @hichris123 Sometimes I want to know, which peer reopened my dupe hammered questions. That's merely power user stuff, right. But seeing the complete timeline may be useful for everyone though.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can access a post's timeline from this url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/<postId>/timeline
```

Which is accessible from this button, under the post's score:

> [image: Timeline button]

You can get to the revision history from this url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/<postId>/revisions
```

Comment: You can get the `<postId>` from the edit link