# Reopen of question can hide dupe close target

Tags: discussion

When an un-edited question closed as a duplicate is reopened, one naturally has no access to an edit history that would expose the duplicate target(s) the question was originally closed toward.

Later, a user wishes to find such information of the dupe target(s) originally proposed.

With no edit history, and a timeline that does not expose duplicate target(s), **what recourse does one have** to determine the original close short of performing a trivial edit to expose it in the edit history?

I present the following example where I did such a trivial edit [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392149). Under 10k view [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tt9S.jpg) as it was subsequently re-dupe closed to the same target and deleted. Timeline [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40392149/timeline).

Note that this meta question is not a duplicate of [How can I see close and reopen history of a question that wasn't edited?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334977) which helps users find the timeline url and offers a nice userscript from Tunaki.

Comment: The question is still marked in the "Linked" section, even after reopening. Doesn't help if there are multiple ones though.

Comment: But as we know that section can grow and even have pagination for overflow beyond N count questions.

Comment: @hichris123 yes I agree. I was too fixated on the timeline and Tunaki's userscript. Thx. Will post for peers to close vote it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no link to the revision history, but you can still go to the link directly by typing it out in the URL bar, just as you would to get to the timeline:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/<postIDgoesHere>/revisions
```

Comment: yep, works like a charm, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40426813/revisions) with no edits. Thanks Servy