# How can I know whether a question is queued for hold review?

Tags: support, on-hold

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852820/visual-studio-2017s-intellisense-doesnt-recognize-masterpage) was reasonably placed on hold, probably because there wasn't enough code to reproduce the problem.

Six hours after it was edited to include reproduceable code (I just set up a test project, so I know it can be done), there's no indication of whether this post has been reviewed and whether it's still in some queue waiting to be taken off hold.

There are also no comments from the hold-placers indicating what would make the post no longer hold-worthy.

I'm sympathetic to the OP because they're using old technology that likely won't get much attention. I'd love to place a bounty and help this person out.

1. Why is a descriptive comment not prerequisite to placing a hold?
2. Is it possible to ascertain whether a post is queued for hold review? If not, why not?

Comment: 3k users can see close votes. Beyond that, you can check [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56852820/timeline) (IIRC reviews only show up after completion). There was [one close vote from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/23420058), so the rest came from outside review.

Comment: @Zoe cool, that's helpful! So after the edit, does the post go back up for review? Or is meta the only recourse?

Comment: It goes into reopen review if it's edited or has reopen votes. Don't know if it's been reviewed in the reopen queue or not, but it doesn't have any reopen votes atm.

Comment: The first edit after the question was put on hold sends the question to the reopen queue. Reopen votes may come from there or from other users getting to the question outside review.

Comment: Makes sense. Will we see in the timeline when review votes (hoping that's the right term) are cast?

Comment: Do note that it's still missing the _minimal_ from _minimal, reproducible example_, a lot of the code isn't necessary to reproduce the issue (all the database stuff for example, since it's not database related), so I wouldn't have high hopes for it getting reopened. If I'd encountered it in the queue that would be a solid _leave closed_ from me.

Comment: @ErikA I considered that, and you're certainly in a better position to evaluate than me, having much more experience. But the code doesn't seem to contain an unreasonable amount of fluff, and it's possible the OP doesn't know exactly what's relevant (evidenced by the lack of code in the original post).

Comment: *"When I compile the solution or website I have errors on recognize MasterPage."* - What errors? I can't see images so I have no idea what OP is talking about. If the errors are in OPs image they should include a textual description if they can't include a stacktrace etc. itself.

Comment: The "**EDIT ANSWER**" text above the codedump isn't going to help it get reopened either. It makes it look a bit like the OP solved it themselves and edited the answer into the question, something people do surprisingly often.

Comment: Fair complaints. It feels yucky that the hold-placers did not leave comments indicating these things (but I get it, people are busy). Also yucky that there's no way for me to get a sense of the current possibility of a re-open (more problematic, because meta becomes the only recourse). But I appreciate y'alls clarification.

Comment: @Michael The point here is, but that's better told to the OP, that if I copy-paste the code provided, I would get an entirely different error (since the connection string would be undefined). So I would need to strip it out myself if I were to reproduce the problem, and then if it were relevant I'd have failed to reproduce it (it isn't relevant ofc). This makes verifying an answer substantially harder. I don't mind a tiny bit of noise, I mind needing to substantially alter the code before reproducing.

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw We *did* leave a comment: *""Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].""*

Comment: @ErikA fair enough, and that's definitely something I could have communicated to OP (they seem to have since fixed the issue). But there's less motivation to put in that effort when it's unclear whether the post has a viable path to non-hold.

Comment: @NickA eh. I basically understood the problem and the code necessary to reproduce. The above critiques are tailored and would be much more helpful (evidenced by the fact that the user clearly read the hold description and was still confused).

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw I won't argue that, they'd be far more helpful, but my point was that there was a comment present. As Eric mentioned as an issue though the *minimal* part wasn't complete. I think just as helpful (in this case) as tailored comments would be more emphasis on the *"the shortest code necessary"* part of the close reason... Also we don't get any notification or anything when a post that we voted to close is edited or pushed into the re-open queue, so there is no way for us to know if it's no longer close worthy without keeping track of it, which we can't reasonably do.

Comment: @NickA fair enough! But still really curious... Is there no way for me to tell for certain that the post failed re-open review? That would help give me clarity to goad the OP to a more on-topic edit (in some hypothetical future post).

Comment: Every post has a [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56852820/timeline). As there is no completed reopen review in the timeline, I would assume that at this moment it is still in the queue.

Comment: I appreciate the friendly and constructive way in which you have conducted this discussion @MichaelCrenshaw. I'd also like to make it clear (as the person who cast the first close vote) that I was hoping to be able to answer the question - there are plenty of us around who still work with Web Forms. It was, alas, not answerable in the state I found it.

Comment: @StephenKennedy you bet! I felt a bit helpless to help out the OP. But now that I've got a better idea how the system works, I'll be in a better spot next time. I appreciate the commenters' patience and help.

Comment: There are currently 3 reopen votes on the question. According to a [comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852820/visual-studio-2017s-intellisense-doesnt-recognize-masterpage#comment100289445_56852820) the issue was resolved by uninstalling a VS update. For me, it therefore seems that the issue _was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_. So, does it make sense to reopen the question?

Comment: @honk The question is open now. I agree with your assessment that the issue was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only tell if a post went through review *after* the review is completed.

You do this by going to the timeline (`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<enter ID here>/timeline`), and seeing if there's an entry for the review queue. You can also see who voted, and what their vote was.

You can see an example of a failed reopen in the timeline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/549/timeline#review_18528935) of [this very old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication).

You can't see if an item is currently in the queue, unless you have a link to their queue entry.

You can assume an item is still in the queue if there is no entry in the timeline and either it has had substantial edits after it's been closed, or if you have >3K rep and see a reopen vote.

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw Remember that posts will only enter the re-open queue from an edit *once*, which is why we encourage the OP to make full edits to their questions rather than having other users make minor edits to a closed post, as that would make it harder for OP to have their question re-opened after they did do a proper edit. Also only [edits within 5 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue) count.

Comment: @NickA that's super helpful to know. I'm guilty of making a lot of micro-edits on my own questions. I wish that info were somehow highlighted on the first edit of an on-hold question.

Comment: Just to confirm - there's still an active review (mods happen to be able to see those on the timeline) - https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23425472... /cc @Michael

Comment: @JonClements nice, thanks! Also helpful to see what the UI is like, for someone < 3k.

Comment: That very old question should have stayed historically locked, yet Community unlocked it... Why? It's been closed and reopened multiple times, too.

Answer (score 2):

Via comments, I learned a few things:

1. One can get a sense of how the hold was placed via the question's timeline.
2. After the first (and *only* first) edit, made within five days of closure, the question goes to a reopen review queue. If there's nothing in the timeline about the review, the question is still in the queue.
3. The OP's second edit, basically adding "why is this on hold?" was counter-productive, because it made the first edit (adding code) less prominent in the reopen review queue.
4. The OP's code is not minimal (there's database stuff that wouldn't work in a reproduction environment).
5. The error(s) should be in text form, not image.

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334977/how-can-i-see-close-and-reopen-history-of-a-question-that-wasnt-edited

Comment: @Michael, you need to take a closer look at the ID from the review, that's the review ID not the question ID, you can't look at the re-open review using that URL

Comment: @NickA aw crud. Is that ID exposed anywhere for folks <3k reputation?

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw Not that I'm aware of unfortunately, it's not even exposed for users >3k until we actually access the review. The only reason mods can is because they can see the review in the timeline while it's in progress

Comment: @NickA no worries. Edited the answer to remove the incorrect URL. Thanks for the heads-up.