# How do I view the Markdown content (source code) for a question where revisions are locked/prohibited?

Tags: support, markdown

How do I view the markup language source code for [***this question***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270967/proper-use-of-the-kbd-tag)?

By hand, I typed [`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270967/revisions`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270967/revisions) into the URL field in my web browser. Appending `/revisions` immediately after the post id number `270967` would usually work just fine. However, the web address [`meta.s[...]/questions/270967/revisions`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270967/revisions) simply redirects to [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270967/proper-use-of-the-kbd-tag) itself.

Comment: There's also more than one revision on that post, so the standard way to get to the revisions page is available _i.e._ [clicking the last revision timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYRNh.png).

Comment: Also, it should be `/posts/id/revisions`, not `/questions/id/revisions`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see close and reopen history of a question that wasn't edited?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334977/how-can-i-see-close-and-reopen-history-of-a-question-that-wasnt-edited)

Comment: I know that's not the exact circumstance here since that question was edited, but it does include the correct link path `/posts/id/revisions` which seems to be the primary issue.

Comment: As noted by a previous commenter, it must be "/posts/" in the URL, not "/questions/". This is the problem. You cannot simply append "/revisions", because the normal URl for a question includes "/questions/" (or, equivalently, "/q/"). Appending "/revisions" has never worked. However, "https://[meta.]stackoverflow.com/posts/id" always works equivalently to "https://[meta.]stackoverflow.com/questions/id" for getting to the question. On this basis, I agree with Henry that this is really a duplicate of the "how-to" FAQ, which explains the correct way to do it. Not a bug, just a misunderstanding.

Comment: Related (though there must be some older ones as well): *[Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332237)*. Also *[List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566)* (mostly hidden features of Stack Exchange)